# Using a SP with a large number of parameters in entity framework?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a SP from an existing database that I must use to create my "person" object in my EF project. I can not map the SP since it is existing and the input values do not match the "person" object, so I assume I have to call it as a function/SP.

My question is, I have a lot of values that I need to pass to it before executing (about 30 input parameters, and 3 output parameters), is there an easy way to code this?

The way I was planning on doing it, was creating the 30 some SQL parameters, and then passing them all to the function, and then executing the function? Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like it to me. Perhaps wrap your 30 values in a class so your function doesn't need 30 arguments?

Comment: There's only one good way to deal with SPs like that.  Delete it.